# Cannot open more apps

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I've been running into an issue with a client's computer. Here's the problem: every so often, Windows doesn't allow him to open any additional apps. The apps that he's currently using work fine. I've ran spyware/virus scans to no avail. I also tried this "fix", but again, no luck: http://weblogs.asp.net/kdente/archive/2004/06/04/148145.aspx

What I mean by "he's not able to open any additional apps" is that, when he tries to open another application, nothing happens, no error message, nothing. This is really hard to troubleshoot as there is nothing that stands out in the event log. It seems as though some limit has been reached. Memory usage seemed to be normal though. Tried troubleshooting it by having procdump monitor explorer.exe and some of his day-to-day apps he's running...nothing

Comment: Could it be Windows XP Starter? It can only run 3 programs at a time.

Comment: Has this just started happening? Have you tried system restore to a point it was working? All Windows updates installed?

Comment: I believe it's windows xp pro, but I'd have to check to be sure. According to the user, yes, this has just started happening a few weeks ago. I ensured all updates were installed.

Answer (score 0):

As more informations are missing, do you use the XP-starter-edition? It can open only three applications. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Starter_Edition

Comment: That's the weirdest restriction I've ever heard of! :/

Comment: @idigas: Coincidentally, XP Starter was a weird edition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a [RAM check](http://www.memtest.org) and a [scan of the hard drive](http://www.hiren.info) for any errors, or are there any errors listed within the Windows Event logs?

My next step would be a windows repair install after running complete [Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org) and [Anti-Virus](http://free.avg.com) scans... Possibly even a 'Live CD' to see if it is hardware related before a long repair-install.

Comment: I've ran malware/virus scans, but this doesn't seem to be the case. But I haven't run though RAM or HDD tests. I might give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, goodluck! :)